# SenderName from Outlook macro is blank

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want to get the `SenderName` and and `To` properties from a `MailItem` object, but they are coming through as blank.

I can see that there is `SentOn`, `Subject` and other properties which are not blank.
Does anyone know why these two are blank?

Here's my code:

```
Sub TestMacro()
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myOlexp As Outlook.Explorer

On Error Resume Next

Set myOlExp = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
For Each myItem In myOlSel
strRawSubj = myItem.Subject
strSender = myItem.SenderName 'blank
strLongTo = myItem.To 'blank
Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
This works if I run Outlook as admin.
Is it possible to get these values without having to run Outlook as admin?

Comment: There is no problem with the code, i am able to get `To` and `Sender Name` of selected item

Comment: what reason would there be for these coming through as blank?

Comment: would suggest you to recreate a module or insert this macro in `this session` of outlook

Comment: @AmbrishPathak it's still blank after I put the code in the "ThisOutlookSession"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try the following...*

*Use the code on regular module*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olMsg As mailitem

    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    '// All print on Immediate Window
    Debug.Print olMsg.SenderName
    Debug.Print olMsg.sender
    Debug.Print olMsg.SenderEmailAddress
    Debug.Print olMsg.Categories
    Debug.Print olMsg.subject
    Debug.Print olMsg.To
    Debug.Print olMsg.CC
    Debug.Print olMsg.ReceivedByName
    Debug.Print olMsg.SenderEmailType

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
Sub TestMacro()

    Dim myOlexp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Selection

'   On Error Resume Next                       ' do not use during development ... hides errors

    Set myOlexp = Application.ActiveExplorer   ' "Application" object already exists
    Set myOlSel = myOlexp.Selection

    For Each myItem In myOlSel
        Debug.Print Len(myItem.Subject)        ' print the length of each string
        Debug.Print Len(myItem.SenderName)     ' maybe the strings are being obfuscated somehow
        Debug.Print Len(myItem.To)
    Next

    Set myOlSel = Nothing
    Set myOlexp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: 0m3r has already provided a working solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: so, did your code fail because you did not declare a mailitem object?