# Get Sender's Email Address in Outlook Macro Without Using MailItem

Tags: vba, email, outlook

The `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` and `MailItem.To` fields are coming through as null unless I run Outlook at admin.

How can I get the sender's email address and the to email address without having to use `MailItem`, or using `MailItem` but without having to run Outlook as admin?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior in OutlookSpy if you click the Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon and select one of these properties?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use 3rd party software at the company I work for.

Comment: How about if you run the following script from Outlook VBA (Alt+F11) - MsgBox Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).SenderName

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: Why does this work but using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127403/sendername-from-outlook-macro-is-blank does not work?

Comment: Now what if you replace Application with, say, App, and App variable initialized first using "set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")" ?

Comment: Now they're null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above (works for the intrinsic `Application` object in VBA, but not if you create a new instance of the `Outlook.Application` object), you are most likely running into the security patch or some weird AV app interaction. If you are using VBA, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is probably your only option. Or figuring out what is going on with your AV app, or installing it if you don't have one installed.